# xampp Apache redirect to tomcat

Tags: apache, tomcat, xampp, port

[image]

Using Xampp on my Windows Server I recently installed some web apps using tomcat. Using the Apache to access phpMyAdmin. After deploying I noticed I access the tomcat webapp using a URL like this: `domain.com:8080/someapp/`.

I do not like that but the internet says its good for some security reasons so I did not change the port from 8080 to 80 in the `server.xml`.

But I want the end-user not to access my app using :8080 in the URL.

How can I redirect my Apache to Tomcat witgout losing my access to phpMyAdmin?